# How to prevent webdriver from being identified?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

I refer to the answer in the link above

I used vim to modify the chromedriver source code

Replace the $cdc_lasutopfhvcZLmcfl field with the same amount of other code

After modification, the chromedrvier can also work properly

But my selenium is still recognized by the site

Such as

https://login.taobao.com/member/login.jhtml?redirectURL=https://www.taobao.com/

This website in China

A manual swipe of the verification code after you enter your account and password will still not pass without selenium

This thing has been bothering me for a long time. I really don't know how to solve it. I hope I can get your help

Comment: If you use Windows, you might consider trying Explorer. Of course IEDriverServer is horrible (okay, to defend the author, it is as good as it can be), as IE does not support the WebDriver protocol (provided you use an old enough IE, e.g you are on Win7). I have not tried it, but would be surprised if it could be detected, considering that not even IE can detect it. Otherwise you could modify the headers on the fly, e.g. with Fiddler.

Comment: Can you provide the exact _url_ you are trying to access as there seems a **space** is present within the _url_ you have provided as `https://login.taobao.com/member/login.jhtml? redirectURL=https://www.taobao.com/` which is getting resolved as `https://login.taobao.com/member/login.jhtml?%20redirectURL=https://www.taobao.com/`. Also let us know if you have a dummy/demo credentials to login.

Comment: I have changed the address and now it is correct

Simply use the modified chromedriver

Browser = webdriver. Chrome ()

The get (url)

After the account and password are entered, the verification code cannot be swiped @Newcontributor

Comment: So did your question got addressed or you are still looking for an answer?

Comment: The problem is not solved, and selenium will still be recognized @Newcontributor

Comment: @jianyi Let us know if you have a dummy/demo credentials to login